# Only able to acces the first element of a modified array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I've been tasked with comparing the values of phone numbers in an array and returning the element whose digits sum to the highest number. To accomplish this, I've decided to replace the "-" in the phone numbers so that the elements contain only digits, then parseInt the strings to compare the digits. However, I'm stuck on the first part.

When I return the array, only the modified first element is returned. How could I rewrite this so that all elements of the array are returned?

```
function largest_phone_number(arr) {


for (var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++) {
        var re = /-/g;
        arr = arr[i].replace(re, "");
        return arr;
        }
    } //largest_phone_number(['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333']);
```

Comment: for a start, `arr[i] = arr[i].replace(re, "");` ... and remove the return statement form the loop ... move it OUTSIDE the loop

Comment: should not return from the for loop

Comment: Use [`Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(e => e.match(/\d/g).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr, 0)));`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x79o0jdm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current context will stop running as soon as you use the keyword `return`.  So, your function will stop after the first iteration of the loop.

Your situation is ideal to use the `Array.map()` function.  I might suggest doing the following:

```
function largest_phone_number(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(elem){
    return elem.replace("-", "");
  });
}
```

This will return a new array without the hyphens.

Comment: That worked really well. I tinkered with map, but wasn't able to get it to work correctly. I used the regExp /-/g instead, which took all the hyphens out of the elements. Thanks!